# how can i create the label when ever i select the spinner value i.e Official and when ever i select spinner value normal hide the label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

[Here i have pasted my Code in GitHub Kindly Look Into it]
{ https://github.com/BollamReddy-Python-Vba/python/commit/710bd80f649968cd19181e0abda21f5164e8ba9f}

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
Window.size = (500, 400)
Window.clearcolor = (0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2)


def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
    print('Selected Process', spinner, 'have text', text)


class LRefConfigAutomation(App):
    config = None

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('LefConfigWindowSection', {
            'PartInputLabel': 'Please Enter your Part No',
            'TypeOfProcessLabel': 'Select Type Of Process',
            'NormalFolderName': 'Enter Normal Folder Name',

        })
        self.config = config

    def build(self):
        config = self.config
        root = FloatLayout()
        lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'PartInputLabel')
        self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .90}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0), halign="left",valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
        self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
        self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
        root.add_widget(self.label)
        with self.label.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.label.pos, size=self.label.size)
        self.txtKemNo = TextInput(pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .90}, size_hint=(None, None),font_name="Georgia", size=(100, 30), multiline=False, hint_text="Part Number")
        root.add_widget(self.txtKemNo)
        lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'TypeOfProcessLabel')
        self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .75}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0), halign="left",valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
        self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
        self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
        root.add_widget(self.label)
        with self.label.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.label.pos, size=self.label.size)
        self.requestsspinner = Spinner(
            # default value shown
            text='Select Process',
            # available values will be binded to the combo
            values=("Normal", "Official"),
            # just for positioning in our example
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(110, 20),
            pos_hint={'center_x': .66, 'center_y': .75}, font_name='Georgia')
        self.requestsspinner.font_size = '14.5dp'
        self.requestsspinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)
        self.requestsspinner.bind(on_click=self.CreateLable)
        root.add_widget(self.requestsspinner)
        runTouchApp(root)
    def CreateLable(self, spinner, text):
        root = FloatLayout()
        print(text)
        if text == "Normal":
            pass
        elif text == "Official":
            config = self.config
            lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'NormalFolderName')
            print(lbl)
            self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),halign="left",valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
            self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
            self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'
            root.add_widget(self.label)
            with self.label.canvas:
                Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
                Rectangle(pos=self.label.pos, size=self.label.size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LRefConfigAutomation().run()
```

Comment: Could you please copy your Code again and check the formatting?

Comment: I'm unable to paste the code Properly , what should i do now, Please help me .

Comment: https://github.com/BollamReddy-Python-Vba/python/commit/710bd80f649968cd19181e0abda21f5164e8ba9f

Comment: i have pasted my code in git hub kindly look in to it

Comment: Your code needs to be here, in the question, preferably as a [mcve]. External links can break, making the question pointless. Especially guthub code is likely to change, again, making the question pointless for others with the same problem. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems. First, your `build()` method is not returning the `root` (which is what it is intended to do). Remove the line:

```
runTouchApp(root)
```

and replace it with:

```
return root
```

Second, your `CreateLable()` is not being called. I suggest changing:

```
    self.requestsspinner.bind(on_click=self.CreateLable)
```

to:

```
    self.requestsspinner.bind(text=self.CreateLable)
```

The third problem is that in `CreateLable()` you are not adding the new `Label` to the display. The `root` that you create in that method has no relation to the `root` of your display. I suggest changing that method to:

```
def CreateLable(self, spinner, text):
    if text == "Normal":
        pass
    elif text == "Official":
        config = self.config
        lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'NormalFolderName')
        self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),halign="left",valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
        self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
        self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'
        self.root.add_widget(self.label)  # add label to the GUI
        with self.label.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.label.pos, size=self.label.size)
```

You might want to delete the canvas instructions at the end of the above method. It is creating an invisible `Rectangle` at the bottom left od your display. The `pos` and `size` of the new `Label` are still at the default values of `(0,0)` and `(100,100)` at that point, so that is where the `Rectangle` is drawn, and where it will stay.

Here is the entire code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
Window.size = (500, 400)
Window.clearcolor = (0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.2)


def show_selected_value(spinner, text):
    print('Selected Process', spinner, 'have text', text)


class LRefConfigAutomation(App):
    config = None

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('LefConfigWindowSection', {
            'PartInputLabel': 'Please Enter your Part No',
            'TypeOfProcessLabel': 'Select Type Of Process',
            'NormalFolderName': 'Enter Normal Folder Name',

        })
        self.config = config

    def build(self):
        config = self.config
        root = FloatLayout()
        lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'PartInputLabel')
        self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .90}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0), halign="left",valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
        self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
        self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
        root.add_widget(self.label)
        with self.label.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.label.pos, size=self.label.size)
        self.txtKemNo = TextInput(pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .90}, size_hint=(None, None),font_name="Georgia", size=(100, 30), multiline=False, hint_text="Part Number")
        root.add_widget(self.txtKemNo)
        lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'TypeOfProcessLabel')
        self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .75}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0), halign="left",valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
        self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
        self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
        root.add_widget(self.label)
        with self.label.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.label.pos, size=self.label.size)
        self.requestsspinner = Spinner(
            # default value shown
            text='Select Process',
            # available values will be binded to the combo
            values=("Normal", "Official"),
            # just for positioning in our example
            size_hint=(None, None),
            size=(110, 20),
            pos_hint={'center_x': .66, 'center_y': .75}, font_name='Georgia')
        self.requestsspinner.font_size = '14.5dp'
        self.requestsspinner.bind(text=show_selected_value)
        self.requestsspinner.bind(text=self.CreateLable)
        root.add_widget(self.requestsspinner)
        return root

    def CreateLable(self, spinner, text):
        if text == "Normal":
            pass
        elif text == "Official":
            config = self.config
            lbl = config.get('LefConfigWindowSection', 'NormalFolderName')
            self.label = Label(text=lbl, pos_hint={"center_x": .66, "center_y": .65}, size_hint=(1.0, 1.0),halign="left",valign="middle", font_name='Georgia')
            self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
            self.label.font_size = '14.5dp'
            self.root.add_widget(self.label)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LRefConfigAutomation().run()
```

Comment: I did as you suggested , But still i'm facing same issue ,whenever i select official label isn't created

Comment: Did you change the `CreatLable()` method? Specifically, changing `root.add_widget` to `self.root.add_widget`?

Comment: yes i did , But still i didn't get any label while click on Official

Comment: https://github.com/BollamReddy-Python-Vba/python/commit/710bd80f649968cd19181e0abda21f5164e8ba9f

Comment: I have pasted the result image in GitHub , like that i want  the output , Could you please look into that

Comment: That is exactly what I get when I run your code with modifications as I described above.

Comment: Could you please paste the full code  that would be helpful to me

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: Thank you So much :)

Comment: Hi John Anderson I need help from your end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210931/discussion-between-bollamreddy-and-john-anderson).